# How to view my complete purchase (just apps, not IAP stuff) history on Apple App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, itunes-store

I have tried many ways but failed to view a full list of my purchase. Does any one know how I can view them all? My first purchased should happen in early 2010. Thanks very much,

Answer (score 1):

The system only displays a subset of purchases at a time. You would need to download them or save your purchase emails to create a comprehensive listing of all purchases.

Comment: I think this is right, but you should clarify which system you're talking about - the OP isn't clear about what he's tried.